# Apps Script Advanced Calendar API - insert new event with Title - Error "Invalid source url:"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm using the "built-in" **Advanced** Apps Script Calendar API (Not the REST API) and trying to create a new calendar event, but I'm getting the error:

> Invalid source url:

I'm getting the calendar ID directly from the calendar, so I don't think it's that.

```
function createCalEvent() {
  var event, calendarId, endTime, newEvent, options, 
      response, resource, startTime, title, url;

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName("Main Calendar");

  calendarId = cal[0].getId();//   
  Logger.log('calendarId: ' + calendarId)

  title = "Test Event Title";

  startTime = "2018-7-18T09:00:00";
  endTime = "2018-7-18T12:00:00";

  resource = {
    "start": {
      "dateTime": startTime,
      "timeZone": "GMT-08:00"
    },
    "description": "Test the description",
    "source": {
      "title": title
    }
  }

  if (endTime) {

    var o = {
      "dateTime": endTime,
      "timeZone": "GMT-08:00"
    }

    resource.end = o;
  } else {
    resource.endTimeUnspecified = true;
  }

  response = Calendar.Events.insert(resource, calendarId);
  Logger.log('response: \n' + response)

}
```

I'm trying to set the title of the event.

Comment: In your request body, when you insert an event with "source", ``source.title`` and ``source.url`` are required. When ``source.url`` is not used, the error of ``Invalid source url: .`` occurs. So for example, can you try ``"source": {"title": title, "url": "http://localhost"}`` by adding "url"? Reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). If this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: You can also check about ``source`` at [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events). ``Source from which the event was created. For example, a web page, an email message or any document identifiable by an URL with HTTP or HTTPS scheme. Can only be seen or modified by the creator of the event.``

Comment: I'm not sure what "source" is?  The documentation states: *Source from which the event was created.*  so I guess it has nothing to do with being able to set the event title.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I noticed that I misunderstand your question. When you want to set the event title for Calendar.Events.insert(), you can set it by including ``summary: "event title"`` to ``resource``. ``source`` is not for giving the event title. Reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events). ``summary: Title of the event.``

Comment: That works.  Thank you.  Please include as an answer.

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: The advanced service is just a client library wrapper for the rest API btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it sets the event title for Calendar.Events.insert(), please include the property `summary` in the request body. `source` is not for giving the event title. So please modify as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
resource = {
  "start": {
    "dateTime": startTime,
    "timeZone": "GMT-08:00"
  },
  "description": "Test the description",
  "summary": "event title", // Added
  // "source": {"title": title} // Removed
}
```

#### Note :

- If you use "source" in the request body, please include both `source.title` and `source.url` like `"source": {"title": title, "url": "http://localhost"}`. When `source.url` is not included, the error of `Invalid source url: .` occurs.

#### Reference :

- [Events: Resource representations](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations)