# Google calendar api request has empty source url

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I use the googleapis calendar_v3 api in javascript to create events by impersonating another user on our domain.
The api returns an error when calling the evemts.insert method. The documentation does also not show any breaking changes for that api from googles side.

the error I receive is the following  `code: 400, errors: [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'invalid', message: 'Invalid source url: .' } ]`

I do not set the source url anywhere, this error and it's origin is a mystery to me. Anyone can help or point me in the right direction?

**code**:

```
  createEvent = (
    oauth_token: string,
    event: calendar_v3.Schema$Event,
  ): GaxiosPromise<calendar_v3.Schema$Event> => {
    return this.calendarAPI.events.insert({
      oauth_token,
      calendarId: 'primary',
      sendUpdates: 'all',
      requestBody: event,
    })
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the insert code (using the Edit link under the question)? It's hard to answer if we don't know how you are using the API, there are different ways to do it AFAIK

Comment: Added it, it's very basic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apps Script Advanced Calendar API - insert new event with Title - Error "Invalid source url:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344520/apps-script-advanced-calendar-api-insert-new-event-with-title-error-invalid)

Comment: What's in `event` in the call that returns an error (just to check if the duplicate proposal can help you)? It may be basic to you because it's your code, but the errors often resides in small details

Comment: Thanks guys, the duplicate proposal resolved the issue. I guess I could not find that post because the titles error message is slightly different from my error